# Are java comparators Type-aware?

Tags: java, types

I wanted a simple way to create a Comparator object based on any given Comparable class, so I coded the ComparatorCreator object, which I believed would look at the type of its generic and return the proper Comparator object that I could use to compare objects of that type. So I wrote the following code to test my idea. my belief would be that since the BackwardsInt class' compareto method is a reversed Comparator, it should be able to compare any two numbers in reverse order. But as it went through the statements, it completely ignored the reversal when it was comparing two ints, and even threw an error. I want to know why this is happening. The comparator I created seems to be aware of the type of the Number I'm passing in its arguments.

(I also got really into bounded wildcards a while back, so if that caused the problem, then oops).

```java
import java.util.Comparator;

public class what {
    public static void main(String[] ignoreme)
    {
        Comparator comp = new ComparatorCreator<BackwardsInt>().getComparator();
        //comp should represent a Comparator<Number> which redirects to BackwardsInt.compareTo
        int big=6;
        int small=2;
        BackwardsInt bbig=new BackwardsInt(6);
        BackwardsInt bsmall=new BackwardsInt(2);

        System.out.println(comp.compare(bbig, bsmall));//prints -1 good
        System.out.println(comp.compare(bbig, small));//prints -1 good
        System.out.println(comp.compare(big, small));//prints 1 why?
        System.out.println(comp.compare(big, bsmall));//throws error?!?
    }
    private static class ComparatorCreator<T extends Comparable<? super T>>{
        public Comparator<? extends T> getComparator()
        {
            return T::compareTo;
        }
    }
    private static class BackwardsInt extends Number implements Comparable<Number>{
        private int val;
        public BackwardsInt(int v)
        {
            val=v;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Number o) {
            double d = o.doubleValue()-val;
            if(d>0)
                return 1;
            if(d<0)
                return -1;
            return 0;
        }

        public int intValue() {
            return val;
        }

        public long longValue() {
            return val;
        }

        public float floatValue() {
            return val;
        }

        public double doubleValue() {
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Comparator comp` .. raw types are bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at your `ComponentCreator`

```
private static class ComparatorCreator<T extends Comparable<? super T>>{
    public Comparator<? extends T> getComparator()
    {
        return T::compareTo;
    }
}
```

If have slightly changed it to make your mistake more clear

```
private static class ComparatorCreator<T extends Comparable<? super T>>{
    public Comparator<? extends T> getComparator()
    {
        return (o1, o2) -> {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        };
    }
}
```

The method reference you used is the same as the lambda I have but it makes the mistake more obvious. If we check your samples one by one we can see the following:

```
comp.compare(bbig, bsmall); // calls bbig.compareTo(bsmall)
comp.compare(bbig, small); // calls bbig.compareTo(small)
comp.compare(big, small); // calls big.compareTo(small)
comp.compare(big, bsmall); // calls big.compareTo(bsmal)
```

The output you received makes sense because `big.compareTo()` will call the `compareTo()` function of the `Integer` class.

Comment: I guess my question turns into: why does java ignore the <BackwardsInt> type in resolving the method?